# Where can I find php-fpm.log and php-fpm.conf on my server?

Tags: php, cgi, fastcgi, fpm

I think I am having problems with the max children limit for `php-fpm`. I am trying to find something in the logs. Where can I find `php-fpm.log` on my server? Running `phpinfo()` shows this:

[image]

I cannot find anything related to `php-fpm` in `/var/log/`.

I am also trying to find the `php-fpm.conf` that is mentioned at https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php. Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:** I found at https://github.com/rlerdorf/php7dev/issues/48 that it asks to edit `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`. In my case, I cannot find that file:

```
root@jai [/usr/local/etc]# pwd
/usr/local/etc
root@jai [/usr/local/etc]# ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4096 Sep 23  2011 ./
drwxr-xr-x. 15 root root 4096 Apr  7 15:02 ../
```

Do I need to create it at `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`?

**UPDATE 2:** I see I have a folder called `ApachePHPFPM` but the file inside (`default_accounts_to_fpm`) is empty:

```
root@jai [/var/cpanel/ApachePHPFPM]# pwd
/var/cpanel/ApachePHPFPM
root@jai [/var/cpanel/ApachePHPFPM]# ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 26 04:44 ./
drwx--x--x 108 root root 12288 Apr 17 13:44 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     0 Mar 26 04:44 default_accounts_to_fpm
root@jai [/var/cpanel/ApachePHPFPM]#
```

**UPDATE 3:** My server had this file:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/etc/php-fpm.conf
```

The file contains this:

```
; Error log file
; Default Value: /var/log/php-fpm.log
error_log = /usr/local/cpanel/logs/php-fpm/error.log
```

That means that my error logs for `php-fpm` are located in this file: /usr/local/cpanel/logs/php-fpm/error.log.

I navigated to `/usr/local/cpanel/logs/php-fpm/` but I could not find `error.log`:

```
root@jai [/usr/local/cpanel/etc]# cd /usr/local/cpanel/logs/php-fpm/
root@jai [/usr/local/cpanel/logs/php-fpm]# ls -al
total 8
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Mar 30  2018 ./
drwx--x--x 6 root root 4096 Apr 16 15:24 ../
root@jai [/usr/local/cpanel/logs/php-fpm]#
```

Comment: what system are you on? how did you install php-fpm?

Comment: I think it was using WHM that `php-fpm` was enabled on my server. My operating system is `Linux abc.example.com 2.6.32-754.27.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 28 14:11:45 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. To be more specific: `Linux version 2.6.32-754.27.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-02.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue 11:45 UTC 2020`.

Answer (score 1):

In `/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php-fpm.conf` I found this line:

```
error_log = /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/var/log/php-fpm/error.log
```

I see the error log files there:

```
root@jai [/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/var/log/php-fpm]# pwd
/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/var/log/php-fpm
root@jai [/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/var/log/php-fpm]# ls -al
total 151456
drwxrwx--- 2 nobody root     4096 Apr 14 17:36 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root     4096 Mar 26 04:42 ../
-rw------- 1 root   root 31536068 Apr 17 17:05 error.log
-rw------- 1 root   root 32102325 Mar 29 03:26 error.log-20200329
-rw------- 1 root   root 51453659 Apr  5 03:36 error.log-20200405
-rw------- 1 root   root 39966549 Apr 12 02:55 error.log-20200412
root@jai [/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/var/log/php-fpm]#
```